# relations in groups with 2 generators

Tags: group-theory

In general, given a group $G=<x,y \vert x^n=y^m=1, yx=x^iy>$, how do we re-express $y^ax^b$ as $x^cy^d$ where $c,d$ in terms of $n,m,i,a,b$?

(Currently I am attempting questions where $i=2$. I find that to calculate $y^ax^b$ step by step every time is extremely time consuming and very easy to make mistake along the way...I've tried to spot a pattern but was unable to...)

Comment: There is a problem, when you say to calculate $y^ax^b$ in terms of what exactly? because for me, $y^ax^b$ is already simplified, when you start to your calculations you're just trying to obtain a more complicated expression. am I wrong?

Comment: @Elaqqad I mean to express $y^ax^b$ as $x^cy^d$ where $c,d$ in terms of $n,m,i$

Comment: it might be something that's completely obvious but i'm too thick to spot..:p

Comment: This is not possible because your expressions $y^ax^b$ depends on $a$ and $b$ and we cannot reduce them to only $n,m,i$, there sust be always something which depends on $a,b$ (I can reduce them to $r$ and $r'$ with $r$ are remainders of some divisoins)

Comment: @Elaqqad sorry i mean in terms of $n,m,i,a,b$ (I will edit my question)

Comment: The best way to express elements of $G$, is $x^ky$ because every element can be of this form

Comment: but not if $m \ne 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** The best way to simplify expressions in $G$ is to write them in the form $x^ky^{k'}$ with $k$ an integer, as a hint you can prove by induction on $a$ (using only $yx=x^iy$) that :
$$y^ax^b=x^{i^ab}y^b$$
Now if we consider $r$ is the remainder after the division of $i^ab$ by $
n$ and $r'$ is the remainder after division of $b$ by $m$ we have $i^ab=r+qn$ with  $q\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq r\leq n-1$ we have $y^ax^b=x^ry^{r'}$.

Comment: This is only how to transform an element of the form $y^ax^b$ to the form $x^ky^{k'}$ and as I said there is no any possible simplification, maybe you can write $y^ax^b$ of the form $y^{r'}x^r$ with $r$ and $r'$ are the remainders after division of $b$ and $a$ respectively by $n$ and $m$, but I don't see more possible way.